# iMap, multiple devices, sync FILTERS, OS X & iOS

Tags: email, sync, apple-mail

I've been googling for awhile and can't seem to find an applications/apps that work the way I want them to.

I have multiple IMAP email accounts. I also use a large amount of filters, it is a pretty good bet that if an email winds up in my inbox it is either junk or from a new contact. Emails that I receive from my usual suspects are filter and moved to IMAP folders, emails from Ed are in the Ed folder, emails from Sandy are in the Sandy folder. Folders are also grouped within folders.

Apple's stock Mail.app handles this workflow fairly well, however when I check with on my iPad, the *rules* are not (yet) applied. This makes sense since Mail.app's rules are applied by Mail.app on my laptop, not on the server. This could be solved if Mail.app and the Mail app would sync their rules, the iPad could apply the rules. But they don't.

I'm looking for an OS X application and an iOS app that lets me have my email hierarchy the same on all platforms. The app must also have the ability to keep copies for offline viewing. I want my email archived on my hard drive, not just in the cloud somewhere.

I'm familiar with gmail's Labels. That may be the only solution but I'm not fond of it. iCloud seems like it could work, someday, but the client is too simplistic.

Answer (score 1):

[Sparrow](http://sparrowmailapp.com/) should work. It's basically a souped-up version of Apple Mail and Mail.app Both the iOS and OS X versions respect folders.